# Hazelcast CacheProvider not able to instantiate

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I am using Hazelcast 3.7 and Hibernate jar 3.
I am trying to use Hazelcast as second level caching. Here is my hibernate configurations.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">com.hazelcast.hibernate.provider.HazelcastCacheProvider</property>
```

While starting my application, here is excpetion which I am getting

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate CacheProvider: com.hazelcast.hibernate.provider.HazelcastCacheProvider
```

Also I have tried to configure

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

But same exception. Is I am missing any configurations? I am going for Hazelcast as second level caching as I want to cluster my application.

Comment: Can you check this?
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/hibernate-2ndlevel-cache
I think you are missing to use hazelcast-all.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue. This is because I was using old Hibernate jars. With `hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar` and `hazelcast-all-3.7.3.jar` issue got resolved.